# Understanding syslog rotation, to implement own syslog rotation

Tags: files, syslog

I am trying to implement a simple syslog server (UDP based). On this , we are  trying to implment SYSLOG rotation feature. Currently the roatation of logs is done by `rename` C API.

By doing this we achieve only renaming the syslog file names. Not the syslog file which is residing inside the gzip file.

So I am trying to understand what is the procedure followed in Linux so that syslog roatation can be implemented for my Windows project.

Answer (score 1):

Usually logfile rotation is handled outside the syslog daemon by e.g. the `logrotate` tool. After rotation a signal is sent to the syslog daemon to reopen all logfiles. This works fine under linux/unix, as it's not a problem to rename files that are opened by other processes; I understand that in Windows this could be more problematic.

EDIT: the logfiles are renamed, e.g. `daemon.log` becomes `daemon.log.0` or (preferably) `daemon.log.20150423`. Either immediately or one cycle later the rotated file is compressed with `gzip` although that technically has nothing to do with logfile rotation itself, it's just for freeing up space and you could choose to save time and not to do the compression, given today's terabyte disks.

Comment: GZ : gzip format..i am cofused how they rename the syslog file which resides inside GZIP file.

Comment: There is no file residing inside a gzip file; the gzip file *is* the file but compressed. It has no own name (well, technically the original name can be recorded but in practice that's never used).